# Split cells from an image of a table

Tags: python, opencv

I have to get the contents of a table image using python and OpenCV.

Image is as follows, Lecturer detail table with lecturer name, subject code: [image]

I need to get the text of the each row. For example:

[image: Table row image]

My current implementation (up to splitting the rows of the table) is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cropped_Image_Location = "/home/shakya/Desktop/Paramore/CM_bot/timeTableDetails/Cropped/"
segmentCount = 0

img = cv2.imread(cropped_Image_Location+"cropped_5.jpg")

edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('edges-50-150.jpg',edges)
minLineLength = 100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/10, threshold=200, lines=np.array([]), minLineLength= minLineLength, maxLineGap=100)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

small = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(small, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
# using RETR_EXTERNAL instead of RETR_CCOMP
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
    mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 0
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, idx, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)

    if r > 0.45 and w > 8 and h > 8:
        cv2.rectangle(small, (x, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        crop_img = small[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        segmentCount = segmentCount + 1
        imageNumber = str(segmentCount)

        cv2.imwrite(cropped_Image_Location+"Lecturer_cropped_" + imageNumber+".jpg", crop_img)

cv2.imwrite(cropped_Image_Location+'lectureAll.jpg', small)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm stuck with splitting the cells of a row.

Comment: Next step is OCR right? This tutorial has a successful implementation https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: If the cells of the table in the image are fixed, then just crop by coords is ok.

Comment: No it's not. The cells are getting changed with the details which are inside of the cell.

Comment: Let me know if you have found a solution I need exactly same functionality to crop rows from the table.

Comment: Shakya RDN, @PiotrK, I am also in similar situation :D Were you able to find the solution? If so, it would be really appreciative, if you could share the solution.

Comment: @ShakyaRDN yes I got this and text recognition you can find full code here https://github.com/PiotrKrosniak/ocrbot

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to find horizontal lines whose length is greater than a certain threshold. After finding horizontal lines you can find (x,y) position of lines to crop the rows.
you can process the image like this

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('D:\Libraries\Downloads\Capture.PNG')
# find edges in the image
edges = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_8U)
# kernel used to remove vetical and small horizontal lines using erosion
kernel = np.zeros((5, 11), np.uint8)
kernel[2, :] = 1
eroded = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_ERODE,
                          kernel)  # erode image to remove unwanted lines

# find (x,y) position of the horizontal lines
indices = np.nonzero(eroded)
# As indices contain all the points along horizontal line, so get unique rows only (indices[0] contains rows or y coordinate)
rows = np.unique(indices[0])
# now you have unique rows but edges are more than 1 pixel thick
# so remove lines which are near to each other using a certain threshold
filtered_rows = []
for ii in range(len(rows)):
    if ii == 0:
        filtered_rows.append(rows[ii])
    else:
        if np.abs(rows[ii] - rows[ii - 1]) >= 10:
            filtered_rows.append(rows[ii])

print(filtered_rows)
# crop first row of table
first_cropped_row = img[filtered_rows[0]:filtered_rows[1], :, :]

cv2.imshow('Image', eroded)
cv2.imshow('Cropped_Row', first_cropped_row)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

you can use filtered_rows to crop the rows of table

**UPDATE:** working cod as of python 3.6.8 - fixed based on http://answers.opencv.org/question/198043/problem-using-morphologyex/?answer=198052#post-id-198052

Comment: Some kind of explanation to go along with the uncommented code would make this answer much better.

Comment: Maybe you can try HoughLines method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054055/python-cv2-houghlines-grid-line-detection

Comment: @user8190410, Could you tell me, why kernel is of size `(5,11)`?

Comment: @user8190410, By the way, your solution worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: @user8190410, Another question, how do you use the same algorithm for vertical lines?

Comment: @explorer `(5,11)` is used according to the problem as above. Infact, it should be `(1,11)` as only 3rd row consists of 1's.

Comment: @explorer to use it for vertical lines, find unique column indices i.e. `cols = np.unique(indices[1])`

Comment: @explorer Also your kernel will become `(11,1)` because now you have to erode vertical lines

Comment: @user8190410 Thanks for your replies. Earlier, I figured that, ```kernel = np.zeros((5,11),dtype=int)
kernel[2,:] = 1``` will create a matrix with 3rd row as ones, which will be used to match the horizontal lines (& then erode/dilate). Is that correct? 
Based on that, I created kernel for vertical lines as you suggested, which seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

first you identify all of the boxes by using contours.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

then get the moment of each of box.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

then you can identify the row. moment represent the middle pixel of the contour area. doc says central of mass of the object

then check same contours with same x values. or in small range (you decide)

combine the ROIs togather. you will have the row.